# Get the last character before a specific part of string in PHP

Tags: php, string, find

I would need a method to get the **last character before a specific substring** in a string.
I need this to check if it's a SPACE before the specific substring, or not.

**I am looking for a function like:**

```
function last_character_before( $before_what , $in_string )
{
    $p = strpos( $before_what , $in_string );

    // $character_before =  somehow get the character before

    return $character_before;
}

if( $last_character_before( $keyword , $long_string ) )
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: its better to provide an example, and your trial code...

Comment: Can't you check whether the string matches `space` + `substring`?

Comment: Why not match the sub string with `strpos` and then -1 on the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the position of matched needle, you just have to substract - 1 to get the character before that. If the position is -1 or 0, there's no character before.

```
function char_before($haystack, $needle) {
    // get index of needle
    $p = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    // needle not found or at the beginning
    if($p <= 0) return false;
    // get character before needle
    return substr($hackstack, $p - 1, 1);
}
```

Implementation:

```
$test1 = 'this is a test';
$test2 = 'is this a test?';

if(char_before($test1, 'is') === ' ') // true
if(char_before($test2, 'is') === ' ') // false
```

PS. I tactically refused to use a regular expression because they are too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
$string = "finding last charactor before this word!";
$target = ' word';//note the space

if(strpos($string, $target) !== false){
 echo "space found ";
}
```

Comment: Although this makes sense the OP's example code does return the character if its a space or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
function last_character_before( $before_what , $in_string )
{
    $p = strpos( $before_what , $in_string );

    $character_before = substr(substr($in_string ,0,$p),-1);

    return $character_before;
}
```